# Shutdown seems to freeze my cpu on dell latitude e7470 under linux

Tags: linux, laptop, cpu, freeze, shutdown

I bought a Dell Latitude e7470 recently. I immediately removed the preinstalled Windows 10, and installed Arch Linux.

It works fine, except for one thing: On shutdown or reboot, at the point where the pc would usually switch off (all processes ended, etc.), the laptop just hangs for around 30-60 secs. While it hangs, the battery led flickers in a pattern that, according to dell's owners manual, signals "CPU failure". After the 30-60 secs, the fan spins up to max rpm, and then the system crashes (just shuts off, doesnt reboot until I press the power button again).

I suspect that somehow, the linux kernel issues the wrong shutdown command to the cpu, but I have very little knowledge on how to figure this out. Can anyone give me any tips on this? The cpu is an i-5 6300.